# VBA Code that can pull values from certain cells and update it too by user input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to fetch the existing values from Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 into Sheet 3 (one at a time) as I change my dropdown value and also to change those values by user input from Sheet3. I am being able to pull the values, have used the following code. Cell B3 is where the dropdown is.

```
Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
    Case "B3"
      Application.EnableEvents = True
      Range("H9").Formula = "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,5,,,$B$3))"
      Range("I9").Formula = "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,5,,,$B$3))"
      Range("J9").Formula = "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(9,5,,,$B$3))"
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Exit Sub
  End Select
```

Also, in my sheets, say, Sheet 1 cell E18, I have put this formula in excel IF($B$3="Sheet1",Sheet3!H$9,Sheet3!E18) ;E18 being self referencing
The issue is the moment I try to overwrite the formula in cells H9:J9 by a user input value, it updates it for Sheet 1 but the moment I change the dropdown to Sheet 2, it updates it too for those values. I want it to pull the existing values from Sheet 2 the moment I change my dropdown value

Comment: Honestly I'm unable to understand your exact need,, please share some sample data or upload the WB on cloud to examine !!

Comment: Its like making a dashboard where: 1. I can see data for any sheet depending upon the sheet name selected from a dropdown and 2. I want to even have the flexibility to make changes to it just by overwriting the value.